# External Website Directly Infringing Facebook's Privacy Policy

Tags: facebook

How do I report directly to Facebook an *external website* that is offering a "Free App Download for Facebook" that is directly infringing upon Facebook's Privacy Policy?

Answer (score 1):

[Facebook's Privacy Policy](https://www.facebook.com/about/privacy/) is a policy between Facebook and users, so it does not apply to apps or external web sites.  The [Facebook Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) apply to apps making use of the Facebook Platform.  In addition, third party apps using Facebook Platform must also have their own Privacy Policy (this is one of the requirements in the Facebook Platform Policies).

If the web site is associated with a Facebook app which is in violation of the Facebook Platform Policies, you can go to the application's canvas page on Facebook (a URL starting with `https://apps.facebook.com/`), click on "Report/Contact this App" at the bottom of the page, and choose the option to report the app for violating the Facebook Terms.  If you don't know the URL, try searching for the application using Facebook search.  Look under the Apps heading or filter to show only Applications.